# How to solve Column 'empID' does not belong to table?

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio, combobox

I have an **Employee** table in my sql database  which has **emp_Id**, **emp_name**, **manager_Id**.
I'm trying to get all the **emp_name** as a LIST and put them in a **ComboBox**
here my sql statement:

```
string sql = "SELECT emp_name FROM Employee";
```

And this how i'm putting them in the LIST

```
public static List<T> GetList<T>(DataTable dt)
            where T : IPopulateColumns, new()
        {
            List<T> TList = new List<T>();
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                T t1 = new T();
                t1.PopulateColumns(dr);
                TList.Add(t1);
            }
            return TList;
```

Here my PopulateColumns method inside the Employee Class: I have fields and properties name for **empId,** **empName**, **managerID** inside the class.

```
 public void PopulateColumns(DataRow dr)
        {

            this.empId = (int)dr["EmpId"];
            this.empName = dr["EmpName"].ToString();
            this.managerId = dr["ManagerID"].ToString();
        }
```

I getting an error that stated " **Columnn 'EmpId ' does not belong to table**

Comment: You only select `emp_name`.

Comment: **Always** retreive the primary key, with stuff like the name. Use it for the value part of hte combo box items. The whole purpose of the UI is to have the user select the key, without him nessesarily knowing about the key.

Comment: But, I have a couple of employees in the table who has the same name. I want to select DISTINCT only in the emp_name column. Can i use? string sql = "SELECT empId, DISTINCT emp_name, manager_id from Employee";

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have the completed code you provided, I recommend you use the following code

to get get all the emp_name as a LIST and add them as the datasource of the combobox.

Code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connstring = @"";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connstring);
            connection.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT emp_name FROM Employee";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            DataSet set = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            adapter.Fill(set);
            var result = set.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(i=>i.Field<string>("emp_name")).ToList();
            comboBox1.DataSource = result;

        }
```